# How to capture opcode executed for a transaction

Tags: geth-debugging

In remix debug mode, we can see opcodes executed line by line for a transaction, is there any way we can print the list of opcode and their corresponding line number(maybe memory address?) when executing a transaction locally on a Geth client connected to a private chain? Maybe we need to instrument the Geth client? 
Some concrete idea or example would be really helpful! I want to collect this information for code coverage purpose.

**New Edit**: I figured out how to use debug.traceTransaction(), however, the returned JSON still misses some info, for example, in the remix debugger, a line of opcode such as

"PUSH1 40"

will only show "PUSH1" in the trace, how can I get the more detailed trace like the ones Remix debugger provides?

Comment: Geth provides [debug_traceTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction) api that allows collecting information of the transaction execution.

Comment: New Edit: I figured out how to use debug.traceTransaction(), however, the returned JSON still misses some info, for example, in the remix debugger, a line of opcode such as

"PUSH1 40"

will only show "PUSH1" in the trace, how can I get the more detailed trace like the ones Remix debugger provides?

Comment: It is supposed you will read the data from the contract bytecode using the value of PC. _The bytes are read in line from the program code’s bytes array_ from Yellow's Paper 60s & 70s: Push Operations.

Comment: about the contract bytecode program counter, where do I get that information? After compiling a solidity contract with Solidity compiler, the bytecodes I get are "Bytecode" and "Runtime Bytecode"(Same thing when clicking details of a compiled contract in remix), I understand one is  the bytecode during deployment, and one is the bytecode after a contract is been deployed, however, both do not contain pc information.

Comment: PC is in the callback of traceTransaction, inside a log entry there's a ['pc' field](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#javascript-based-tracing). The bytecode of a contract is returned by [eth.getCode](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode), it is the runtime.